# ESLint - FATAL ERROR: Scavenger: semi-space copy Allocation failed - JavaScript heap out of memory

Tags: angular, typescript, eslint, typescript-eslint

I have recently upgraded my Ionic/Angular application to the latest of everything. Of relevance:

```
 "@angular/*": "^16.1.1",
 "@angular-eslint/builder": "16.0.3",
 "@angular-eslint/eslint-plugin": "16.0.3",
 "@angular-eslint/eslint-plugin-template": "16.0.3",
 "@angular-eslint/schematics": "16.0.3",
 "@angular-eslint/template-parser": "16.0.3",

 "eslint": "^8.44.0",
 "eslint-plugin-import": "2.27.5",
 "eslint-plugin-jsdoc": "46.2.6",
 "eslint-plugin-prefer-arrow": "1.2.3",
 "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^5.59.7",
 "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^5.59.7",
 "eslint-config-prettier": "^8.8.0", 

 "ts-node": "~10.9.1",
 "typescript": "^5.1.3",
```

I am running in inside of vscode, that has the ESLint extension (dbaeumer.vscode-eslint)

And note I get the following error in the ESLint output, and of course there is no linting:

```
[Info  - 6:07:32 AM] ESLint server is starting.
[Info  - 6:07:33 AM] ESLint server running in node v16.17.1
[Info  - 6:07:33 AM] ESLint server is running.
[Info  - 6:07:34 AM] ESLint library loaded from: C:\dev\myapp\node_modules\eslint\lib\api.js

<--- Last few GCs --->

[37792:00000138004CC000]    31705 ms: Scavenge 3937.6 (4076.3) -> 3936.2 (4077.1) MB, 4.3 / 0.0 ms  (average mu = 0.850, current mu = 0.817) allocation failure; 
[37792:00000138004CC000]    31717 ms: Scavenge 3938.3 (4077.1) -> 3937.1 (4078.6) MB, 4.1 / 0.0 ms  (average mu = 0.850, current mu = 0.817) allocation failure; 
[37792:00000138004CC000]    31732 ms: Scavenge 3939.9 (4078.6) -> 3938.5 (4088.1) MB, 4.5 / 0.0 ms  (average mu = 0.850, current mu = 0.817) allocation failure; 


<--- JS stacktrace --->

FATAL ERROR: MarkCompactCollector: young object promotion failed Allocation failed - JavaScript heap out of memory
 1: 00007FF6237416D6 node::Buffer::New+47862
 2: 00007FF62374184D node::OnFatalError+317
 3: 00007FF626146E13 v8::internal::WebSnapshotDeserializer::UpdatePointersCallback+787
 4: 00007FF626146DA7 v8::internal::WebSnapshotDeserializer::UpdatePointersCallback+679
 5: 00007FF6261BF067 v8::CppHeap::CollectGarbageInYoungGenerationForTesting+65495
 6: 00007FF624F477B3 v8::CppHeap::GetHeapHandle+201107
 7: 00007FF622518ACE v8::CppHeap::CollectStatistics+232910
 8: 00007FF622518592 v8::CppHeap::CollectStatistics+231570
 9: 00007FF622523232 v8::CppHeap::CollectStatistics+275762
10: 00007FF624822873 Cr_z_uncompress+2817971
11: 00007FF624822B82 Cr_z_uncompress+2818754
12: 00007FF622519583 v8::CppHeap::CollectStatistics+235651
13: 00007FF62250E63B v8::CppHeap::CollectStatistics+190779
14: 00007FF62250A194 v8::CppHeap::CollectStatistics+173204
15: 00007FF6224F945D v8::CppHeap::CollectStatistics+104285
16: 00007FF6224F6C87 v8::CppHeap::CollectStatistics+94087
17: 00007FF6224F4093 v8::CppHeap::CollectStatistics+82835
18: 00007FF624F27151 v8::CppHeap::GetHeapHandle+68401
19: 00007FF624F19090 v8::CppHeap::GetHeapHandle+10864
20: 00007FF62262308A v8::internal::TickSample::GetStackSample+114602
21: 00007FF5BFED7DBC 
[Info  - 6:08:07 AM] Connection to server got closed. Server will restart.
true
```

I can find other post with similar errors that suggest using `--max-old-space`, but not how to apply this to ESLint.

I have exactly the same setup in other projects and all is fine. This project is larger than the others, but I would it call it huge.

What can I try to resolve this?

Comment: try to add 

"scripts": {
  "lint": "node --max-old-space-size=4096 ./node_modules/eslint/bin/eslint.js src"
},

in your package.json

Comment: @BugsCreator -  I tried that, but unfortunately I still get the error

Answer (score 0):

There is an option in Angular.json to tell the linter to match certain files:

```
 "projects": {
    ...
      "architect": {
        "lint": {
          "builder": "@angular-eslint/builder:lint",
          "options": {
            "lintFilePatterns": [
              "src/**/*.ts",
              "src/**/*.html"
            ]
          }
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).